# How to give user trying to copy URL other URL than the A HREF value?

Tags: javascript, html

I use skeleton framework to sketch tabs inside IFRAME widget. Each tab has code like this:

```
<a class="active" href="#skeletonTab0" target="_top">Name of tab</a>
```

href pointed to #.... is required for the menu to work.

When user right clicks on this tab and selects "copy URL" he gets the URL of the widget host http://dummyhost.com/index.php#skeletonTab0.

But because the widget is embedded on site http://importantnews.com i would like him to copy URL to:

http://importantnews.com/index.php?showTab=0

Is there any way to make it so that a will have href pointed to #skeletonTab0 but when user tries to copy the URL he will get proper URL on important news?

Basically the question is if i can provide user trying to copy URL from a href other href than actual href?

EDIT: Today, i've found a working example of something similar to what i try to obtain, but still figure out how to make this work for me.

Look at this site:
https://plus.google.com/100784670873737717716/posts/PAEa7sFcKMS

1. When you click "What i learned" it redirects you to http://www.readwriteweb.com.
2. When you copy the URL of this link you get http://www.readwriteweb.com.
3. But when you click the link plus.url.google.com* redirecting to http://www.readwriteweb

Have you any ideas?

Comment: No. JS has very little control over the clipboard and copy operations, and given you've got pages loading from two completely different domains, you're going to run into all sorts of cross-domain security restrictions as well.

Comment: you mean something like `onmousedown="var tmp=this.href;this.href='http://importantnews.com/index.php?showTab='+this.href.split('#')[1].replace(/skeletonTab/,'')" onmouseup="this.href=tmp"`

Comment: i suppose something like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no.  What you could do is have the link point to `http://importantnews.com/index.php?showTab=0` but register an onclick listener so that when the link is clicked, the default action (i.e. going to that link) is cancelled and replaced by your desired action.

Comment: location.href = '#skeletonTab0';

Comment: i've tried this way but skeleton file tabs.js shows contantLocation is undefined in line 28.

Comment: line 28: var contentLocation = $(this).attr('href');